# Adding a NavigationLink to a GroupBox

Tags: swiftui, groupbox, swiftui-navigationlink

I want to be able to click a GroupBox and it navigate me to another view. I tried implementing the following code and got the errors :

1. Cannot convert value of type 'NavigationLink<Text, some View>' to expected argument type 'GroupBoxStyleConfiguration'
2. Type '() -> ()' cannot conform to 'StringProtocol'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols

I wanted to know if there is a way to use Groupboxes to change views and if so how ?

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    // MARK - Properties
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
          ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            VStack(spacing: 10) {
        // MARK: - SECTION 1 : Daily Catch-up
                GroupBox(
// The errors start below 
                    NavigationLink({
                        WellnessLabelView(labelText: "Daily Catch-up", labelImage: "chevron.right")
                        ) {
                            Divider().padding(.vertical, 4)
                            HStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 10) {
                                Text("This app was developed with the idea that expectant families deserve easy access to resources.")
                                    .font(.footnote)}
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make your own `GroupBoxStyle` https://itnext.io/swiftui-groupbox-for-ios-bb16aa71469c

```
struct HealthGroupBoxStyle<V: View>: GroupBoxStyle {
var color: Color
var destination: V
var date: Date?

@ScaledMetric var size: CGFloat = 1

func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: destination) {
        GroupBox(label: HStack {
            configuration.label.foregroundColor(color)
            Spacer()
            if date != nil {
                Text("\(date!)").font(.footnote).foregroundColor(.secondary).padding(.trailing, 4)
            }
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right").foregroundColor(Color(.systemGray4)).imageScale(.small)
        }) {
            configuration.content.padding(.top)
        }
    }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
}
}
```